# How do I filter data from cloud firestore twice?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-test

I want to check if a user has a string ’Level' with any number in his document.

> Level: int

If this is the case, the future should return true and false if not.
That’s the code I’m trying it with:

```
class StufenService{
  String userID;
  StufenService(this.userID);

  final CollectionReference userTodos =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');

  Future checkIfStufeExists() async {
    await userTodos.where('Stufe' is int).get();
    final data = QuerySnapshot.data.documents.where(userID);
    if (data.exists){
      return true;
    } else
      {return false;}
  }
}
```

First I filter out all users who have ’Level': int in their firebased document. Then I want to check if the current user is among the users.

The data after the QuerySnapshot is underlined in red:

```
The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.
```

Can someone help me to implement my plan?
Maybe the whole thing has to be done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this, I find it most useful to keep the [FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying) and [Firestore reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) handy. Based on those, you code should be something like:

```
final CollectionReference userTodos =
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userTodos');

Future checkIfStufeExists() async {
  var query = userTodos.where('Stufe', isEqualTo: 42); // First condition
  query = query.where("userId", isEqualTo: userID);    // Second condition
  final querySnapshot = await query.get();             // Read from the database
  return querySnapshot.size > 0;                       // Check if there are any results
}
```

Comment: Yes. I always recommend being more explicit in the return type, so saying `Future<bool>`.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the returned value of the where statement.
The class QuerySnapshot does not have .data static getter. In order to access the returned value from firestore you need to do something like that:

```
...
final snapshot = await userTodos.where('Stufe' is int).get();
final data = snapshot.data;
...
```

Comment: I've changed it your way, but data still is underlined in red. >The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'.